# Rust ownership, how to return a ref for a struct?

Tags: rust, ownership

I generate an instance A from instance B's method and managed by B, but I want return A. How to implement this?

For [this codes (playground link)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=36d16e5b02b500b3d9b59b77f68a2a34) I want generate a `history` for the RedPacket, managed by RedPacket (push into the Vec) and return `history` ref to print, but the compiler throw out: cannot move out of `history` because it is borrowed

How implement this? Or is this a right way in rust world?

Comment: Please see what constitutes a [mre]. The code has to be in the question itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn’t right way in only “Rust world”, it’s completely wrong in whole programming world. 1. Local variables are stored on the stack, so after function call they are deleted. 2. You’re trying to move your local variable after borrowing it. You are trying to return reference to invalid buffer, and compiler prevents it.

[You can return a reference to the last `Vec` member though](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=b470f5af317b9116154db56f1c572034):

```rust
self.histories.push(history);

self.histories.last()
```